# Reading a PVOID in c#, how many bits should I read?

Tags: c#, usb

I'm reading from a USB packet that has a URB type. The URB header defined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540409(v=vs.85).aspx as

```
 struct _URB_HEADER {
    USHORT      Length;
    USHORT      Function;
    USBD_STATUS Status;
    PVOID       UsbdDeviceHandle;
    ULONG       UsbdFlags;
 };
```

How many bits should I be reading for the PVOID?

Comment: I am going to guess you should be sending a value the same size as **Handle** which would be determined by the operating system.

Comment: give this article a read: [Marshaling Opaque Pointers: a Special Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

Comment: 32 or 64, depending on the bitness of the process.  It is IntPtr in managed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments - reading through them, it looks like using

```
 byte [] ptr_bytes = rdr.ReadBytes(System.IntPtr.Size);
```

will provide the size of the pointer correctly depending on the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Since that's a pointer type, then it depends on your platform. 32 bits for x86; 64 bits for x64.

I'm not well-versed with those libraries but should you be using those fields though? The link you shared says "Reserved. Do not use".

**Edit**:
Disregard the last statement. I just realized that the structure is just the header. Of course you need to know that field's size in order to get to the body. :)