# How is HANDLE in C++ mapped to .NET

Tags: c, handle

A structure in C is:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD num_conversions;      /* INPUT: total # of conversions to write to sample_values, unless cycling. */
    FLOAT conversion_rate;      /* INPUT: interrupts per second  */
    FLOAT conversion_rate_final;/* OUTPUT: the actual conversion rate programmed into the clock  */
    BOOL  cycle;                /* INPUT: when done with num_conversions, restart at the beginning of the buffer?  */
    BOOL  internal_clock;       /* INPUT: use the internal clock (82c54) ? */
    BYTE  low_channel;          /* INPUT: lowest channel number to perform A/D conversion on  */
    BYTE  high_channel;         /* INPUT: highest channel number to perform A/D conversion on  */
    BOOL  external_gate_enable; /* INPUT: A/D dmm, dmm-16 only  */
    BOOL  internal_clock_gate;  /* INPUT: Set internal gating on or off (refer to manual) */
    DSCSAMPLE  *sample_values;       /* I/O:   pointer to the user's sample buffer */
    BOOL  fifo_enab;            /* INPUT: Fifo operation flag for int sample/scan modes. */
    WORD  fifo_depth;           /* INPUT: Fifo depth (if fifo mode used) */
    DWORD dump_threshold;       /* INPUT: Threshold at which to dump the sample buffer */
    BOOL  channel_align;        /* INPUT: if true, the interrupt will automatically realign the channels each cycle */
    BYTE  clksource;            /* INPUT: (PROM only): 0 for 100KHz, 1 for 10MHz internal clock source.*/
    BOOL FIFOThreshold;         /* INPUT: 0-2048, indicates level at which FIFO will generate an interrupt if FIFOEnable = 1 */
    HANDLE hWait_buffer;        /* Internal use: For synchronization of user buffer.*/
    HANDLE hsignal_buffer;      /* Internal use: For synchronization of user buffer.*/
} DSCAIOINT;
```

Absent the two HANDLE elements it was working, but now with them, it is not.   in VB.NET:

```
DSCAIOINT
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, Pack:=1)>
Public Structure DSCAIOINT
    Public num_conversions As Integer      '/* INPUT: total # of conversions to write to sample_values, unless cycling. */
    Public conversion_rate As Single       '/* INPUT: interrupts per second  */
    Public conversion_rate_final As Single '/* OUTPUT: the actual conversion rate programmed into the clock  */
    Public cycle As Boolean                '/* INPUT: when done with num_conversions, restart at the beginning of the buffer?  */
    Public internal_clock As Boolean       '/* INPUT: use the internal clock (82c54) ? */
    Public low_channel As Byte           '/* INPUT: lowest channel number to perform A/D conversion on  */
    Public high_channel As Byte          '/* INPUT: highest channel number to perform A/D conversion on  */
    Public external_gate_enable As Boolean '/* INPUT: A/D dmm, dmm-16 only  */
    Public internal_clock_gate As Boolean  '/* INPUT: Set internal gating on or off (refer to manual) */
    Public sample_values As IntPtr         'Pointer to unmanaged memory - each measurement is 2 bytes, conver to short
    Public fifo_enab As Boolean            '/* INPUT: Fifo operation flag for int sample/scan modes. */
    Public fifo_depth As Short              '/* INPUT: Fifo depth (if fifo mode used) */
    Public dump_threshold As Integer       '/* INPUT: Threshold at which to dump the sample buffer */
    Public channel_align As Boolean        '/* INPUT: if true, the interrupt will automatically realign the channels each cycle */
    Public clksource As Byte    '/* INPUT (PROM only): 0 for 100KHz, 1 for 10MHz internal clock source.*/
    Public FIFOThreshold As Boolean         '/*  0-2048, indicates level at which FIFO will generate an interrupt if FIFOEnable = 1
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)> Public hWait_buffer As IntPtr
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)> Public hsignal_buffer As IntPtr

End Structure
```

How do we map the HANDLE from C into .NET? It seems that these are used only internally in C.

Comment: Given the fact that the `HANDLE` datatype is actually a PVOID or, void *, declaring them as IntPtr seems a bit funky.  Perhaps this thread will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674923/reading-a-pvoid-in-c-how-many-bits-should-i-read

Comment: The title mentions C++; the content mentions C# and C.  Please sort things out so that the question is self-consistent.  Is `typedef` really a part of C# as the spiel before the first code fragment claims?

Comment: It depends. `IntPtr` is the usual way to go *iff* you acknowledge that it is a low-level API where the handles will not be garbage collected. Examples include `Graphics.GetHdc()` or `Font.GetHfont()` for example. In some cases it is useful to have handles whose ownership is transferred to the calling C# code, in which case `SafeHandle` is used. Specifically for marshalling, there exists also `HandleRef`, which unlike `SafeHandle` doesn't guarantee freeing through GC; its purpose is keeping objects alive during P/Invoke calls. The correct answer depends on the native API you're using.